# I keep getting the "USB inserted" sound whenever I plug or unplug something to a power socket. Should I worry?

Tags: windows-7, usb, power-supply, lenovo-laptop

I own a Lenovo G510. I use

- a cooler base
- external mouse
- keyboard
- monitor
- 2:1 speakers

Whenever I plug something to a wall socket that is near to the one that I use to power everything (when logged in windows) I get the usb inserted sound. I am not sure if that happened from when I first bought my laptop but I observed it now, nearly 9 months after I purchased it.

I assume that due to the power consumption changing a little at the moment I plug a device to the socket, something misleads windows to act like it detects external hardware. It annoyed me a little and thought I should search for it but I couldn't find anything.

In General, Lenovo products have a bad reputation when it comes to power leaks. Do you think that that's the case? and if yes, should I try to repair it?

Comment: the stuff you mentioned (I use a cooler base, external mic, keyboard and monitor *is there any other?*) Are they connected to the same Electrical Socket **AND** to the PC via USB ?

Comment: Yes, keyboard and cooler are connected to the pc via usb and mouse is connected on the hub of the cooler.PC, Monitor, 2:1 speakers and an office lamp ( I forgot to mention) are all on same the same socket. Propably it would be a good idea to distribute them equally.

Comment: What I was trying to say is that if you have a device such the USB hub which is connected to the same electric socket as the the laptop and **ALSO** connected to the laptop via **USB**, then most likely there will be an electric disruption when you plugin/out other devices from the socket. The question is, what kind of socket are you using? if it's wall plugin one then make sure you are using a Level -A one or even better use a high quality electric socket extender. Most Likely it's the mouse getting disturbed since it's connected to the weak hub which in turn connected to the laptop.

Comment: The hub is powered from the laptop through usb port. But what you said made sense. I actually tried unplugging everything and the sound didn't occur when I connected something to the wall socket. I think it is caused by some disruption in one of the usb3 ports (where the keyboard is plugged).